# Grizzly error pops up every time

Tags: apt, openstack, source

`apt-get` is not known on line 3 in  source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/grizzly.list.
When I go into this file I have to write down some commands as written in openstack manual doc's:

```
deb http://archive.gplhost.com/debian grizzly main
deb http://archive.gplhost.com/debian grizzly-backports main
apt-get update
apt-get install gplhost-archive-keyring
```

After I've written them down, the next step is to write down another command to upgrade the system

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

but when I execute it, the error pops up every time as I mentioned above.

Comment: Please remove the lines `apt-get update
apt-get install gplhost-archive-keyring` from your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/grizzly.list` file and post the errors that you get here.

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/grizzly.list` file should look like this:

```
deb http://archive.gplhost.com/debian grizzly main
deb http://archive.gplhost.com/debian grizzly-backports main
```

Comment: ok.thanks alot...if i get any error ill write it down here ok...n please can u send me an easy website where i can install openstack manually and without any errors...this is the guide that im using right now

Comment: docs.openstack.org/grizzly/basic-install/apt/content/basic-install_controller.html#basic-install_controller-intro

Comment: @ali Did this answer fix the original problem you were having? If so, please click the green check mark by the answer so people know that this solution does indeed fix the problem you had.